# JSQL Parser throws exception while executing INSERT statement with SELECT and SELECT with subselect

Tags: sql, parsing

I am facing invalid sql exception while using JSQL parser for the below query

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS(ID,NAME, COUNTRY) SELECT * FROM SUPPLIER WHERE COUNTRY ='FRANCE'
```

I have executed this query and can insert rows, but I am facing Invalid SQL exception when parsing using JSQL Parser

Comment: You need to enter column names instead of * in select statement.

Comment: Where is your ID and Name being inserted from?